# Excel Macro Goes into Endless Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on this macro and function for a while.  The function works fine when I just run it by itself, but when I try to put it into a For loop it repeats forever and never increments.  I'll start with the main macro.

```
Sub Run()
    Dim shrt As Worksheet: Set shrt = Worksheets("Shortages")
    Dim sTbl As ListObject: Set sTbl = shrt.ListObjects("Shortages_T")
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim x As Integer

    shrt.Range("H3") = "Can Build"
    
    'x = 9
    For x = 9 To 14 Step 1
        Set xRng = sTbl.ListColumns(x).DataBodyRange
        shrt.Cells(3, x) = BldQty(xRng, x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

If I comment out the loop and manually increment x, it works fine.  Once I put it in the loop, it just endlessly repeats and never increments.  I've checked with a Print.Debug.  The function below is what I'm trying to call with it.  I checked the debug and it just keeps running the same range and column over and over again.

```
Function BldQty(xRng As Range, scol As Integer) As Long
    Dim shrt As Worksheet: Set shrt = Worksheets("Shortages")
    Dim sTbl As ListObject: Set sTbl = shrt.ListObjects("Shortages_T")
    Dim use As Worksheet: Set use = Worksheets("Useage")
    Dim uTbl As ListObject: Set uTbl = use.ListObjects("UseTable")
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim mdl As String
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim qp As Double
    Dim div As Double
    Dim low As Double
    Dim col As Integer
    
    BldQty = xRng(1)
    scol = scol - 1
    
    For Each Cell In xRng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(xRng) <= 0 Then
            BldQty = 0
            Exit For
        Else
            mdl = Cell.Offset(0, -scol).Value
            'VLOOKUP equivalent
            qp = uTbl.ListColumns("Component").DataBodyRange.Find(mdl).Offset(0, 1)
            div = Cell / qp
            If div < BldQty Then
                BldQty = div
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End Function
```

Am I calling it wrong in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByRef instead of ByVal?
I'm not sure about what your code shall do, but

```
shrt.Cells(3, x) = BldQty(xRng, x)
```

goes to

```
Function BldQty(xRng As Range, scol As Integer) As Long
```

where scol ist passed by reference
And in this function you change scol so it returns its new value to x
Try

```
Function BldQty(xRng As Range,ByVal scol As Integer) As Long
```

ByRef is the default in VBA